# videojs multiple sources of same type but different paths

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, video.js

I am trying to use videojs with cordova, which works fine.  I would like to have multiple sources of a file declared via JS.  The idea is the a video file could "potentially" be in multiple locations, but will only actually exist in one of them.  To my understanding, if videojs cannot play a source, it trys the next.  In the below DOES NOT WORK example, it should ignore the first source because the file does not exist, but does not seem to try the 2nd source eventhough the file exists in that directory.  Per the videojs docs http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#Methodssrc it allows an array, but does not say if it allows multiple of the same type.

cordova.file.dataDirectory = the files directory of my app, we will assume that myvideofile.mp4 will always exist in this path.

**WORKS** - assuming myvideofile.mp4 actually exists in directory

```
example_video_1.src(
{type:"video/mp4", src:cordova.file.dataDirectory+"myvideofile.mp4" }
);
```

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
example_video_1.src([
{type:"video/mp4", src:"/some/directory/file/is/not/in/myvideofile.mp4" },
{type:"video/mp4", src:cordova.file.dataDirectory+"myvideofile.mp4" }
]);
```